# jQuery having problems selecting element from a loaded div

Tags: jquery, html, load, nested

So I have a container div, within it, using .load I load some content from db, after the .load the result will be something like

```
<div id="results">
  <div id="a1" class="search-result"></div>
  <div id="a2" class="search-result"></div>
</div>
```

As I understand it, I should be able to select the nested div's by using $("#results .search-result") but I just cant get it to work. If I try:

```
$("#results .search-result").click(function() {
 alert('click');
}
```

it just doesnt seem to work. It does work if I use:

```
$("#results").click(function() {
 alert('click');
}
```

the only thing I can think of is that because the nested div's are loaded using .load then it might not be able to see them?

any help?

Comment: I got it working using a callback on the .load, not sure if this is the right track

Answer (score 1):

If those search results is added after the fact you need to use `live()` instead.

```
$("#results .search-result").live("click", function() {
  alert('click');
});
```

Plus your code had a syntax error (note the final line). It's good practice to look at your errors console to see these kinds of JS errors.

Lastly I'm assuming your snippet is a simplification because what you have is (depending on your CSS) zero height so you might not be able to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

The event handlers are attached to the DOM elements in your example, and are getting erased when the div is loaded because the elements are replaced.  Try this instead:

```
$("#results .search-result").live('click', function() {
 alert('click');
});
```

[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is a handler that sits up at the document level instead capturing the clicks as the bubble up...and get erased with the .load()

Answer (score 0):

`$().click()` just adds the click handler it matching element that exist at the time the `click()` function is called.  If you want the event handler added to elements that are added later, use the `live()` function